# Dependecy between build server OS with generated binaries

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, msbuild, operating-system

I have a C++ and C# based code base (fairly large code base) which builds with Visual Studio. This application is Windows only and uses Win32/MFC/ASP.NET etc. Currently the build server we use to do the build is on Windows Server 2008 R2. Due to end of support of 2008 R2, I need to move the build server to a newer OS. If I use same Visual Studio version and Windows SDK, I can run build on newer OS and run the generated binaries on OS such as Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2019, Windows 10 right? Is there any dependency on the OS of the build server on the generated binaries?

Comment: no, the build operating system doesn't matter

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks, is there any documentation available from Microsoft or anywhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you worry too much about that. You do not have to care much about that.

The generation of binary files, dependency on OS server are up to build tool and VS IDE itself, has nothing to do with the OS version.

**Especially the Build tool**, the build tool parses your project to generate the corresponding binary file, so if your build tool is consistent, then the generated file is consistent.

**And** the **Build Tool** is a part of VS and when you migrate your project into a new sever, as long as you are using the same VS IDE, there is no problem.

**For OS**, you only need to ensure that the current OS version is compatible with the vs ide and you can install the current vs IDE. And current OS should meet the current installation requirements of VS, such as [VS2019 system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements#visual-studio-2019-system-requirements).

**In fact**, there is currently no clear document to explain the problem, and **Microsoft** has not deliberately designed that, so you don't need to care about that. Just keep moving on with your work.